# Zend-mail sending email Connection Timed Out error

Tags: gmail, zend-mail

I am trying to set-up a registration form that sends a welcoming email to the new member.  The form works just fine on my localhost, but when trying to upload it to the remote server I get a "Connection Timed Out" error at the top of the page when the submit button is used.

I am using my teacher's remote server so I have only limited access to the server.

```
$mailhost = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mailconfig = array('auth'      => 'login',
                    'username'  => 'myemail@gmail.com',
                    'password'  => 'xxxxxxxx',
                    'ssl'       => 'ssl',
                    'port'      => '465');
$transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp($mailhost, $mailconfig);
Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($transport);

$mail = new Zend_Mail('UTF-8');
      $mail->setBodyText($text, 'UTF-8');
      $mail->setBodyHtml($html, 'UTF-8');
      $mail->setFrom('myemail@gmail.com', 'from me');
      $mail->addTo($email, $name);
      $mail->setSubject('Welcome to the page');
      $success = $mail->send();
      if(!$success) {
        $errors = true;
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out that my teacher's server blocks smtp which was causing the time out error.